# ExtJS 4 MVC accordion with dynamic clickable contents from json

Tags: extjs, extjs4, accordion, extjs4.1, dataview

I need up insert/add child panels to an accordion.  Each of these child panels should have it's title using 'field' value in the data (see below), and the contents of each child should be (labels or a displayfield or ??) as long as it's clickable.  The json data from the server is as below:

```
data: [{
    'field': 'cities',
    'values': [{
        'value': 'DC',
        'count': 5
    }, {
        'value': 'SF',
        'count': 2
    }, {
        'value': 'NYC',
        'count': 4
    }, {
        'value': 'Nashville',
        'count': 4
    }]
}, {
    'field': 'beaches',
    'values': [{
        'value': 'obx',
        'count': 1
    }, {
        'value': 'ocean city',
        'count': 2
    }, {
        'value': 'myrtle',
        'count': 4
    }]
}, {
    'field': 'planets',
    'values': [{
        'value': 'mercury',
        'count': 1
    }, {
        'value': 'venus',
        'count': 2
    }, {
        'value': 'earth',
        'count': 4
    }, {
        'value': 'mars',
        'count': 1
    }, {
        'value': 'jupiter',
        'count': 2
    }, {
        'value': 'uranus',
        'count': 4
    }, {
        'value': 'neptune',
        'count': 1
    }]
}]
```

Rendering works!! :)

But there's no way for me to get a working click event.  Ultimately, the click listener needs to give me access to the value selected + the 'field' value. (for example, 'planets', 'jupiter').

This should be easy but I'm unable to get it working.  At first I tried nested for loops and creating the components on the fly, but could not add a working click handler (perhaps b/c I'm doing the work within a store load handler function?).  I also tried a dataview within the panel (passing in just the array), but the itemSelector isn't triggering.  I've tried 'div.facet', 'div.facet_item', (and a few others etc) based on the  code, but no luck  - it may have been b/c I didn't know how to select them in the this.control() of my controller:

```
'panel[itemId=pnlFacets] > panel > dataview': {
    itemclick: me.facetSelect
}
```

and the tpl for the dataview attempt:

```
var tplFacet = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="facet">',
            //ignore - (this is handled in title of panel) '<label class="facet_field">{facetName}</label>',   
            '<tpl for="facetEntries">',
                '<div class="facet_item">{value}&nbsp;&nbsp;({count})</div>',
            '</tpl>',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```